# Найти содержимое в строке

Tags: php

```
/url/url/(Nw==)?_ajax=true
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как найти в строке содержимое между **()** ?

Comment: Регулярка: `\((.*?)\)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если такая конструкция будет лишь одна в строке и в скобках будут любые символы, то:

```
$string = '/url/url/(Nw==)?_ajax=true';
preg_match('/\((.*?)\)/', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Comment: Это применимо только к скобкам? Например, если я скобки заменю на **|**, то это уже работать не будет? Спасибо!

Comment: @Евгения тогда вместо `\(` и `\)` надо будет писать просто `|` потому что `(` и `)` - специальные символы в регулярках и если они участвуют в выражении - надо экранировать.